# Entity Framework 6.1.1 - How to check if property is ignored from an entity in SaveChanges method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

**Scenario:**

I have following set of entities:

```
public interface IAuditable
{
    DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    string CreatedBy {get;set;}
    string LastModifiedBy {get;set;}
    DateTime? LastModifiedDate {get;set;}
}

public abstract class BaseEntity: IAuditable
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy {get;set;}
    public string LastModifiedBy {get;set;}
    public DateTime? LastModifiedDate {get;set;}
}

public class Product: BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Order : BaseEntity
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
}
```

and following DbContext:

```
public class AuditDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public AuditDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
            : base(nameOrConnectionString)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Products>()
            .Ignore(t => t.CreatedDate);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
            .Ignore(t => t.LastModifiedBy);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
            .Ignore(t => t.LastModifiedDate);
        }

        public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            SetAuditableProperties();
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }

        private void SetAuditableProperties()
        {
            foreach (var auditableEntity in ChangeTracker.Entries<IAuditable>())
            {
                if (auditableEntity.State == EntityState.Added ||
                    auditableEntity.State == EntityState.Modified)
                {
                    string userName = "ABC";
                    DateTime dateTimeNow = DateTime.Now;

                    auditableEntity.Entity.LastModifiedDate = dateTimeNow;
                    auditableEntity.Entity.LastModifiedBy = userName;

                    if (auditableEntity.State == EntityState.Added)
                    {
                        auditableEntity.Entity.CreatedDate = dateTimeNow;
                        auditableEntity.Entity.CreatedBy = userName;
                    }
                    else
                    {                      
                        auditableEntity.Property(p => p.CreatedDate).IsModified = false; //TODO: Set this property if mapped otherwise dont execute this line
                        auditableEntity.Property(p => p.CreatedBy).IsModified = false; //TODO: Set this property if mapped otherwise dont execute this line
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Observe I'm Ignoring some properties form entities in OnModelCreating and setting Auditable properties inside SaveChanges method by overriding it. Now, when I try to create new entity it works as expected but when I try to update an existing entity it throws exception.

**Problem:**

Let's say I try to update Product entity it throws following exceptions:

*"Member 'IsModified' cannot be called for property 'CreatedDate' on entity of type 'Products' because the property is not part of the Entity Data Model"*.

Same is true for 'Order' entity but for 'LastModifiedBy' and 'LastModifiedDate' properties.

How can I check if a property is ignored from entity inside 'SetAuditableProperties' method? So that I can set 'IsModified' accordingly.

**P.S.** I can find out [NotMapped] properties but when I use the ModelBuilder to ignore a column, I cannot detect these.

Comment: are you aware that, with your configuration `CreationDate` is not part of the model, that is `CreationDate` will never be nor read nor written to the database ?

Comment: @tschmit007 that may sound odd but many places (my current employer as well) use those fields only when querying the database directly and they are set with default values on the database side

Comment: @tschmit007 It's just isolated scenario 99% of my data model have these properties mapped. So 99% of the time these properties will be read and written to database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The EF6 is over encapsulated and most of the metadata is hidden inside internal classes/members.

I see two relatively easy ways to resolve your issue.

Generally you could use [`DbEntityEntry<TEntity>.CurrentValues`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry%601.CurrentValues);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) property of type [`DbPropertyValues`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbpropertyvalues(v=vs.113).aspx), which in turn has [`PropertyNames`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbpropertyvalues.propertynames(v=vs.113).aspx#P:System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbPropertyValues.PropertyNames) property of type `IEnumerable<string>`, which can be used to check for existence of a property name (the non mapped properties are not included in that list):

```
if (auditableEntity.CurrentValues.PropertyNames.Contains(nameof(IAuditable.CreatedDate)))
    auditableEntity.Property(p => p.CreatedDate).IsModified = false;
if (auditableEntity.CurrentValues.PropertyNames.Contains(nameof(IAuditable.CreatedBy)))
    auditableEntity.Property(p => p.CreatedBy).IsModified = false;
```

Another way for this particular case is to utilize the fact that the `Property` method returns `DbPropertyEntry` instance with `IsModified == false` for ignored properties (only the setter throws exception):

```
if (auditableEntity.Property(p => p.CreatedDate).IsModified)
    auditableEntity.Property(p => p.CreatedDate).IsModified = false;
if (auditableEntity.Property(p => p.CreatedBy).IsModified)
    auditableEntity.Property(p => p.CreatedBy).IsModified = false;
```

Of course you could encapsulate both logics in a custom (extension) methods.

Comment: It worked like a charm. However, I'm wondering from where you find this that "Property method returns DbPropertyEntry instance with IsModified == false for ignored properties (only the setter throws exception)". I'm unable to find this from documentation also I tried to explore source code but couldn't find this. Help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You are right, I didn't mention that, but I didn't find that "fact" documented, so simply it's my finding by experiment (try and see, trial and error). In my test I was modifying the ignored property, and `IsModified` was `false` all the time (and `OriginalValues` is throwing exception).

Answer (score 0):

I'm unaware of any way to query the model builder for this outside of the scope of setting the configuration - but there is a little easier of a way to perform this task using attributes

On your properties to be ignored attribute them with `[NotMapped]`, then you would perform this for each property you want to check before updating in your audit method:

```
foreach (var auditableEntity in ChangeTracker.Entries<IAuditable>())
{
    var ignore = Attribute.IsDefined(auditableEntity.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("CreatedDate"), typeof(NotMappedAttribute))
    if (!ignore) {
        auditableEntity.Entity.CreatedDate = dateTimeNow;
    }
}
```

Comment: This may have been solution in case I have used [NotMapped] attribute or all of my entities don't have these properties mapped. This is problematic in case an entity have this property mapped.

Comment: I can find out [NotMapped] properties but when you use the ModelBuilder to ignore a column, I cannot detect these.

Comment: ahh - yeah the point of this answer was to propose an alternative to your current system.  sometimes looking outside the current box is helpful, but if you can't modify your current workflow then this won't solve your issue